# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I'm new to rails and just cannot seem to find the issue. I've been googling for a while now and searching on here. I think i'm just missing something really simple that im not catching.

The error message I'm getting is.

"Can't mass-assign protected attributes: image"

The error according to 'Applications Frames' is in the photos controller here around line 13.

```
8     @photo = Photo.new
9     @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
10   end
11 
12   def create
13     @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
14 
15     if @photo.save
16       flash[:notice] = "photo uploaded."
17       redirect_to galleries_url
18     else
```

In my photo.rb page I have the following:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :photo

    has_many :photos
    validates_presence_of :title
    validates_uniqueness_of :title

    belongs_to :gallery

end
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `image`? Is it an attribute of photo?

Comment: show you db schema please.

Comment: Could you post your view?

Comment: I'm trying to attach my code but it's just showing up in a huge cluster. Anyway, I figured it out by additional research on here. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:photo]` includes an `:image` key.

`Photo.new({ hash of things including an :image key })` is trying to set the `:image` attribute on a new `Photo`.

Assuming there even is an `:image` attribute for that model, you'll need to set `attr_accessible :image` on your model in order for Rails to let you set `:image` in any operation where you pass it a hash of attributes.

See the [Rails attribute security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) for background info.